# Hormander's identity

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\alpha=(\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n})$ a multi-index. We define

$$P^{(\alpha)}(\xi)=\dfrac{\partial^{|\alpha|}P}{\partial\xi_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\dots\partial\xi_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}}(\xi)$$
for $\xi=(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{n})$

and
$$D^{\alpha}=(-i)^{\alpha}\dfrac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial\xi_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\dots\partial\xi_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}}.$$

Now, let $u,v :\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{C},$ where $\Omega$ is domain, that is, open and connected.
Then, by Hormander's Formula

$$P(D)(uv)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\dfrac{D^{\alpha}u}{\alpha !} P^{\alpha}(D)v.$$

We will consider P(D) a linear differential operator with constant coefficients and $u=x_{k}$ and $v=\varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty},$ this formula would be

$$P(D)(x_{k}\varphi)=x_{k}P(D)\varphi+P^{k}(D)\varphi.$$

But I couldn't get to that.

In this case, just have a sense in $\alpha=(0,\dots,0)$ and $\alpha=(0,\dots,1,0,\dots,0)$ kth coord.

In $\alpha=(0,\dots,0),$ $\dfrac{D^{\alpha}x_{k}}{\alpha!}P(D)\varphi = x_{k}P(D)\varphi$. Its ok.

Now is the problem.

In $\alpha=(0,\dots,1,0,\dots,0),$ $D^{\alpha}x_k= -i.$

We can write P like be $\displaystyle P(\xi)=\sum_{|\beta|\leq m}a_\beta\xi^{\beta}=\sum_{|\beta|\leq m}a_\beta\xi_{1}^{\beta_{1}}\dots\beta\xi_{n}^{\beta_{n}}$

Then $P^{k}(\xi)=\sum_{|\beta|\leq m}a_\beta \beta_{k}\xi_{1}^{\beta_{1}}\dots\beta_{k}^{\alpha_{k}-1}\dots\xi_{n}^{\beta_{n}}$

Now i guess we need to change $\xi_{j}$ by $-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \xi_{k}}$ then obtain
$$P^{k}(\xi)=\sum_{|\beta|\leq m}a_\beta \beta_{k} (-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \xi_{1}})^{\beta_{1}})\dots (-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \xi_{k}})^{\beta_{k}-1})\dots (-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \xi_{n}})^{\beta_{n}})$$

And now, what can I do? Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks basically correct to me. ( I did not check carefully about  the details regarding possible sign errors involving $\pm i$). The essence of the  formalism  encapsulated in the Hormander identity is that the constant coefficient operator $P(D)$ can be manipulated by treating it as a polynomial $P(w)$ instead.  In essence in your example what you denote as the operator  $P^k(D)$ is simply the first-order partial derivative of the polynomial $P(w)$ with respect to the  quantity $w_k$; yielding $\frac{\partial P(w)}{\partial w_k}$. Then the multivariable $w$ is replaced with the multivariable partial derivative symbol $D$. You expanded out this expression explicitly.Nothing more can be done to simplify it further.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. But how could I retrieve P^{k}(D)?